# How to connect to a specific port on Apache server

Tags: apache, port

I am very new to apache server so I cannot figure out how to connect to a specific port number say, 8888.

I am using a mac running MAC OS Lion and should I open web sharing, file sharing and remote login? I've done these following steps in [this article](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/how-to-turn-mac-os-x-lion-into-a-web-server). And then I need to connect to a specific port number and look at some files. But I cannot figure out how. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to a specific port, use `http://localhost:SPECIFIC_PORT`, e.g. `http://localhost:1234`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I typed this url in web browser and it did direct me to a certain web page. However I need to view some files under certain directory, so can I access to it through terminal? Could you kindly tell me how? Thanks!